# Facebook-Share-Button posts some information which I dont want to share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hide

Using the FB-Share-Button posts a Message on FB which contains my Company-Name in the last line. Sadly I cant post the screenshot, because I havent enough reputations.

Is it possible to disable this? Or how can I hide this information?

Thank you for your support!

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Apperently there is no way to hide the company-name. But there is a solution to change the information. It is taken from the html-meta-tag "author". So any changes in this tag have effect on the shown words.

Facebook caches this information for some circumstances, changes may not appear in time.

Martin